Does legislation on transgender healthcare affect medical researchers?
I have a very simple question that I’m struggling to find an answer for online. Over the last several years, several countries and many states in America have passed legislation that ban medical providers from providing certain treatments to transgender people. There’s a lot of existing writing on the arguments for and against such bans.
One of the arguments that is made in favor of these bans is that there is not enough scientific evidence supporting the use of the treatments. I’m worried that these bans could prevent more research from being conducted. How can the efficacy of a treatment be studied if it can’t be provided? Or are there research carve-outs?
I’d really appreciate a source for how this kind of medical legislation impacts medical research.

I think the point is not that the legislators want to see more research, they want to see less treatments.

I completely agree. This is the point I’m trying to demonstrate. I’m just having a hard time finding anything written about how these laws will negatively affect researchers. Very understandably, there is a lot more writing on how these laws will negatively affect trans people.

The lawmakers who make these laws don't care about scientific research. They oppose these treatments on ideological and political grounds, regardless of the efficacy.

As an analogy, allowing this research would be like opposing the death penalty but allowing research on the effectiveness of different methods of capital punishment.

A parallel example could be the widespread action of circumcision in USA. Attempts to study this have had to be called off for ethics reasons, related to the pain and damage caused to baby; yet the practice continues because "there is no evidence of the harm it causes"

There seems to be a bit of confusion here. I don't know if it's purposeful, or just a side effect of how the media is portraying these issues. But there is a considerable medical, ethical and philosophical difference between transgender healthcare for adults, and such equivalent healthcare for minors. The question and answers should clearly reflect those differences. Especially since this is not the only area where there is highly significant divergence in laws for adults, and those same laws for minors (marriage, legal consent, contract law, professional licensure, criminal law, etc....).

This question was cross-posted on MedicalSciences.SE: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/34251/does-legislation-on-transgender-healthcare-affect-medical-researchers

@ouflak While there are differences between adults and minors, the people who want to ban transgender care also seem to have the belief that trans folk shouldn't exist in the first place.  So any answer has to include that aspect, an aspect that isn't present in the other areas of law you mentioned (although same sex marriage and, and even now divorce are being targeted)

@ouflak I'm not sure why that distinction would be relevant to my question. While different bans can target different age groups, the effect on research could be the same, no? If you're studying the efficacy of treatment options for adults, you'd be affected by bans on trans healthcare for adults, and if you're studying the efficacy of treatment options for children, you'd be affected by bans on trans healthcare for children. The way legislation affects the research environment seems indifferent to such distinctions.

The people saying there's a lack of data tend to severely underrepresent the amount of data there is, or misrepresent or cherry-pick the data itself (but this is independent of whether or not there is enough data to support the use of any given treatment).

@Joe, " While different bans can target different age groups, the effect on research could be the same, no?" Definitely no. That's why there are specific medical fields that specialize in such things as pediatrics, child psychology, neo-natal care, and so on. Research on the implementation and effects of adult transgender care is undoubtedly related, but perfectly legal and under no threat of ever being otherwise. The question should be clear or it invites exactly such false perceptions and hypothetical socio-political discussion instead of relevant answers.

@PeterM, "... the people who want to ban transgender care also seem to have the belief that trans folk shouldn't exist in the first place." Perhaps a completely fair opinion, but that's not the law - none of the existing nor any of the proposed laws. Unless this forum's guidelines have changed radically, we should be clear that you are asking about transgender healthcare for minors, which is a vastly more controversial subject. Laws on that particular subject could perhaps affect medical research into that specific area. There are examples of prohibitions affecting research (stem cells).

@ouflak I only made a comment.  I'm not asking anything.  Did you mistake me for someone else?

@ouflak "Research on the implementation and effects of adult transgender care is undoubtedly related, but perfectly legal and under no threat of ever being otherwise" ─ this simply isn't true. Texas HB4754 and the original version of Oklahoma SB129 would make it a crime to provide such care to adults up to age 26, with no exception for research. Likewise Kansas SB12 and South Carolina S274 for adults up to age 21.

Those bills (for people over the specified age) and bills in other states (e.g. Ohio and West Virginia) also impose strict and medically unnecessary restrictions on such care for adults, amounting to as close of a ban as the Republican legislators in those states think they can get away with. So in reality there are clear threats.

@PeterM, "Did you mistake me for someone else?"  Are you being facetious?  Because ouflak pulled a quote directly from your comment directed at him and addressed the core of the issue that you seem to be missing, (minor vs adult) and you didn't even acknowledge the point.

@MichaelHall He also said this "we should be clear that you are asking about transgender healthcare for minors" which is not true.

@PeterM, in the context of his original comment "The question and answers should clearly reflect those differences." he is not stating things as they are, but recommending that people clearly distinguish them. Because they are very different issues, and delineating them would improve and clarify the Q & A.


I’m worried that these bans could prevent more research from being
conducted. How can the efficacy of a treatment be studied if it can’t
be provided? Or are there research carve-outs?

Your concerns are real and legitimate and there are not exceptions for research in any of the statutes that I have reviewed (there are about two dozens of them and I haven't read them all).
These concerns are exactly that kind of Catch-22 issue came up with marijuana. Marijuana is classified in U.S. federal law as a Schedule I drug because it was considered to have no legitimate medicinal purpose, but its illegality barred all research except specific studies expressly authorized with federal legislation.
The concern isn't quite a strong in the case of transgender health care, because it is legal in roughly the same number of states where it is not legal (before considering legal challenges to the laws), and research results are being generated in places where it is legal.
This was not true of marijuana research in the early days, as it was illegal everywhere in the U.S. (and still is under federal law), and was illegal in many other countries that might do research as well (even in countries where it was tolerated, like the Netherlands).
Indeed, some of the strongest research evidence in support of transgender health care comes from countries other than the U.S. and U.S. states that have not enacted bans at this time. See, e.g., Maria Anna Theodora Catharina van der Loos, MD, Sabine Elisabeth Hannema, PhD, Daniel Tatting Klink, PhD, Prof Martin den Heijer, PhD, Chantal Maria Wiepjes, PhD, "Continuation of gender-affirming hormones in transgender people starting puberty suppression in adolescence: a cohort study in the Netherlands" The Lancet (October 20, 2022). DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/S2352-4642(22)00254-1 (Some of the other relevant literature is cited here).
Pending Constitutional Litigation.
The constitutionality of transgender health care bans, under both state and federal constitutions, is also an active subject of litigation, which leaves the status of these laws partially undetermined. Some of this is summarized at the bottom of this answer, but the most important of these cases is the pair of cases, from Tennessee and Kentucky, which are pending before the U.S. Supreme Court.
The U.S. Supreme Court has agreed to consider a case from Tennessee in its next term that challenges that state’s gender-affirming care ban for young people. This concerns a Tennessee law that bans gender affirming hormone treatments for patients under the age of 18. The U.S. Court of Appeals for the 6th Circuit has kept bans of this type in place in Tennessee pending the U.S. Supreme Court appeal, after the Tennessee was blocked by a U.S. District Court judge who was reversed by the 6th Circuit on appeal because the 6th Circuit applied only a low rational basis test to the constitutionality of the law, relying upon Dobbs v. Jackson Women's Health Organization, 597 U.S. ____, the case in which the U.S. Supreme Court on June 24, 2022, reversed Roe v. Wade. The Septmeber 28, 2023 ruling of the 6th Circuit in the case (by a 2-1 vote), known as I.W. v. Skrmetti,can be found here (it also addresses a parallel case challenging a similar Kentucky statute).
The Statutes At Issue In The Upcoming SCOTUS Case
The statutes are summarized at one point in the court opinion as follows:

Tennessee’s and Kentucky’s statutes classify based on a minor’s sex as
assigned at birth.  Tennessee prohibits medical procedures when sought
to “[e]nabl[e] a minor to identify with, or live as, a purported
identity inconsistent with the minor’s sex” or to “[t]reat[] purported
discomfort or distress from a discordance between the minor’s sex and
asserted identity.”  Tenn. Code Ann. § 68-33-103(a).  Kentucky
likewise prohibits procedures “for the purpose of attempting to alter
the appearance of, or to validate a minor’s perception of, the minor’s
sex, if that appearance or perception is inconsistent with the minor’s
sex.”  Ky. Rev. Stat. § 311.372(2).

The full text of Tennessee statute states:
Section 68-33-103 - Prohibitions

(a) (1) A healthcare provider shall not knowingly perform or offer to
perform on a minor, or administer or offer to administer to a minor, a
medical procedure if the performance or administration of the
procedure is for the purpose of:
(A) Enabling a minor to identify with, or live as, a purported
identity inconsistent with the minor's sex; or
(B) Treating purported discomfort or distress from a discordance
between the minor's sex and asserted identity.
(2) Subdivision (a)(1) applies to medical procedures that are:
(A) Performed or administered in this state; or
(B) Performed or administered on a minor located in this state,
including via telehealth, as defined in § 63-1-155.
(b)(1) It is not a violation of subsection (a) if a healthcare
provider knowingly performs, or offers to perform, a medical procedure
on or administers, or offers to administer, a medical procedure to a
minor if:
(A) The performance or administration of the medical procedure is to
treat a minor's congenital defect, precocious puberty, disease, or
physical injury; or
(B) The performance or administration of the medical procedure on the
minor began prior to the effective date of this act and concludes on
or before March 31, 2024.
(2) For purposes of subdivision (b)(1)(A), "disease" does not include
gender dysphoria, gender identity disorder, gender incongruence, or
any mental condition, disorder, disability, or abnormality.
(3) For the exception in subdivision (b)(1)(B) to apply, the minor's
treating physician must certify in writing that, in the physician's
good-faith medical judgment, based upon the facts known to the
physician at the time, ending the medical procedure would be harmful
to the minor. The certification must include the findings supporting
the certification and must be made a part of the minor's medical
record.
(4) The exception in subdivision (b)(1)(B) does not allow a healthcare
provider to perform or administer a medical procedure that is
different from the medical procedure performed prior to the effective
date of this act when the sole purpose of the subsequent medical
procedure is to:
(A) Enable the minor to identify with, or live as, a purported
identity inconsistent with the minor's sex; or
(B) Treat purported discomfort or distress from a discordance between
the minor's sex and asserted identity.
(c)(1) It is not a defense to any legal liability incurred as the
result of a violation of this section that the minor, or a parent of
the minor, consented to the conduct that constituted the violation.
(2) This section supersedes any common law rule regarding a minor's
ability to consent to a medical procedure that is performed or
administered for the purpose of:
(A) Enabling the minor to identify with, or live as, a purported
identity inconsistent with the minor's sex; or
(B) Treating purported discomfort or distress from a discordance
between the minor's sex and asserted identity.

The full test of the Kentucky Statute is as follows:

311.372   Prohibition on treatments to a minor for purpose of attempting to alter the appearance or perception of the minor's sex --
Exceptions -- Penalties.
(1) As used in this section:
(a) "Minor" means any person under the age of eighteen (18) years; and
(b) "Sex" means the biological indication of male and female as
evidenced by sex chromosomes, naturally occurring sex hormones,
gonads, and nonambiguous internal and external genitalia present at
birth.
(2) Except as provided in subsection (3) of this section, a health
care provider shall not, for the purpose of attempting to alter the
appearance of, or to validate a minor's perception of, the minor’s
sex, if that appearance or perception is inconsistent with the minor's
sex, knowingly:
(a) Prescribe or administer any drug to delay or stop normal puberty;
(b) Prescribe or administer testosterone, estrogen, or progesterone,
in amounts greater than would normally be produced endogenously in a
healthy person of the same age and sex;
(c) Perform any sterilizing surgery, including castration,
hysterectomy, oophorectomy, orchiectomy, penectomy, and vasectomy;
(d) Perform any surgery that artificially constructs tissue having the
appearance of genitalia differing from the minor's sex, including
metoidioplasty, phalloplasty, and vaginoplasty; or
(e) Remove any healthy or non-diseased body part or tissue.
(3) The prohibitions of subsection (2) this section shall not limit or
restrict the provision of services to:
(a) A minor born with a medically verifiable disorder of sex
development, including external biological sex characteristics that
are irresolvably ambiguous;
(b) A minor diagnosed with a disorder of sexual development, if a
health care provider has determined, through genetic or biochemical
testing, that the minor does not have a sex chromosome structure, sex
steroid hormone production, or sex steroid hormone action, that is
normal for a biological male or biological female; or
(c) A minor needing treatment for an infection, injury, disease, or
disorder that has been caused or exacerbated by any action or
procedure prohibited by subsection (2) of this section.
(4) If a licensing or certifying agency for health care providers
finds, in accordance with each agency's disciplinary and hearing
process, that a health care provider who is licensed or certified by
the agency has violated subsection (2) of this section, the agency
shall revoke the health care provider's licensure or certification.
(5) Any civil action to recover damages for injury suffered as a
result of a violation of subsection (2) of this section may be
commenced before the later of:
(a) The date on which the person reaches the age of thirty (30) years;
or
(b) Within three (3) years from the time the person discovered or
reasonably should have discovered that the injury or damages were
caused by the violation.
(6) If a health care provider has initiated a course of treatment for
a minor that includes the prescription or administration of any drug
or hormone prohibited by subsection (2) of this section, and if the
health care provider determines and documents in the minor's medical
record that immediately terminating the minor's use of the drug or
hormone would cause harm to the minor, the health care provider may
institute a period during which the minor's use of the drug or hormone
is systematically reduced.
Effective: June 29, 2023

A review of the exact scope of each of these statutes is beyond the scope of a Law.SE answer, although some summaries and links to allow for further research can be found below. However, while most of these bans have "grandfather clauses" for people who are in the midst of receiving these treatments, I am not aware of any that have an express exception for medical research.
Other Laws
The current state of transgender health care bans is summarized on the following map:

(Source)
This map has a number of footnotes:

Notes (and see the "Citations" tab or click "Citations & More Information" below the map legend for more information about every
state):
-Arizona banned surgical care for transgender minors in 2022, but in 2023 a new governor issued an executive order with "shield" style
protections for transgender health care that is still legal in the
state. Go to the transgender healthcare "shield" Equality Map to learn
more about these laws.
-Multiple states have "grandfather" clauses, "weaning off" clauses, or limited exceptions for some transgender youth and/or for some types of
medication. Click "Citations" to read more detail about each bill or
to access the law's language directly.
Bans Permanently Blocked
The following laws are permanently blocked from being enforced, though
appeals may be ongoing. Transgender youth should still be able to
access care legally.
-Arkansas: In June 2023, a federal judge permanently blocked the state's 2021 ban, ruling it unconstitutional. However, the state has
said it will appeal the ruling, and the state also passed a new law in
2023 (effective 90 days after the legislature adjourns) that will
allow individuals who receive gender-affirming care as minors (or the
family members of those minors) to sue their medical providers for
malpractice, among other provisions.  The 2023 permanent block builds
on an earlier temporary block issued in July 2021.
Bans Temporarily Blocked (In Full or In Part)
The following laws are at least partially blocked from being enforced,
though these court cases are still ongoing. Transgender youth should
still be able to access care legally to the extent each of these
blocks allow.
-Montana, fully blocked: In Sept 2023, a state district court temporarily blocked the state's ban on youth's care from being
enforced while the lawsuit continues.
Bans Not Yet in Effect
The following laws are not yet in effect. Transgender youth should
still be able to access care legally to the extent each of these
situations allow.
-New Hampshire: The state's ban will not go into effect until January 1, 2025.
Recommended citation:
Movement Advancement Project. [Year of access]. "Equality Maps: Bans
on Best Practice Medical Care for Transgender Youth."
https://www.mapresearch.org/equality-maps/healthcare/youth_medical_care_bans.
Accessed [September 24, 2024].

A July 3, 2024 story from National Public Radio generally corroborates the source above.
A report from April of 2024 with detailed statutory and case law citations can be found here.

Oh my gosh this is so thorough thank you so much. I need to read through all of this carefully. I really appreciate your help!!

“Dobbs v. Jackson Women's Health Organization, 597 U.S. ____” — What do the underscores mean here?

@JanusBahsJacquet It means that a page number for the case has not yet been assigned in the U.S. reports volume of case reports identified yet.

"Indeed, some of the strongest research evidence in support of transgender health care comes from countries other than the U.S. and U.S. states that have not enacted bans at this time." I think it's important to note that this evidence does not necessarily support the "affirmation" model, and may instead support "watchful waiting" where hormonal or surgical intervention is delayed in favour of psychological therapy. That is to say research does support transgender health care in general, how would it not, but it doesn't always agree on what that health care is.

@Crazymoomin The actual results of the research is beyond the scope of Law.com and not suitable to discuss here in the comments.

@ohwilleke I agree, though I think it may be relevant here since only some interventions have been outlawed in some of the states. And while other countries haven't banned  some interventions, they have been deemed experimental which greatly restricts their use when you have socialized healthcare.

@Crazymoomin For the purposes of my question, I'm not interested in the research per se, but how the legislative environment affects the possibility and likelihood of future research being conducted at all.

@Joe Unfortunately both models I named aren't just a scientific battleground, but an ideological one. Which side you are on is often more influenced by the politics of your medical social network than published papers. So science, ideology and the law all get mixed up together.

@Crazymoomin my question has nothing to do with the ideological battleground, the scientific battle ground, nor the models of health care. I am merely trying to understand the way this legislation affects the research environment. This could be a ban on bandaids, and my question would remain the same. To the best of my knowledge, these healthcare bans are quite unusual in that therapies aren’t usually legislated like this. But I am not a doctor nor a lawyer, so I’m trying to get more information.

@Joe I understand. My original intention was to add context to the answer as many people make the assumption that "heath care" in a transgender context means "surgery and hormones" and not talking therapy, and I think it needed clarification. I'm not trying to goad you or ohwilleke into an ideological argument if you think that is my intention. But I do think if you want to understand the law more deeply you are going to have to get into the true complexities of transgender medicine, which includes competing care models.

@Joe It's also important to not that the "affirmation" model is by far the dominant one in the US where it is legal, which will have some impact on the legislation.

@Joe it affects the research environment to the extend that it may outlaw clinical trials in some areas, but it shouldn't outlaw development of treatments up until that point. So if say Kansas outlaws providing puberty blockers to minors you could still do the lab work in Kansas but you couldn't give the resulting drug to minors in Kansas but have to do that stage of your trials in for example Oregon.

@Crazymoomin unless accompanied by legislation that outlaws informed consent for transgender people and forces either criminalisation of transgender care or classifies gender dysphoria as being pathological (and thus requiring a rigid medical diagnosis before treatment is allowed).
